# How come there is a physics tag in stack exchange Maths

Tags: discussion, tag-management

I was browsing through the tags when I found this. And the questions were concerned to mechanics the physics tag is misleading and hold no purpose as there is already a site for that.

Comment: I'm only seeing down votes but no one seems to say any thing?

Comment: You might be seeing downvotes here with no comment as many of the people reading this see the question as being so unenlightened that they do not even know what to say to you. Here they just downvote if they disagree with the premise, so take no offense there. If you still can not see how this idea of not having a physics tag in a mathematics website makes little or no sense to many readers, apply some serious reflection, and add that context. I personally am at a total loss for understanding how anyone could not understand this, but at least I said something as per your implied request.

Comment: Ok thanks @J.W.Perry I'm new so I was only thinking that's all

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The tag exists for several reasons:

1. There are questions with this tag. Answered questions are rarely migrated to another site; old questions are almost never migrated. So, whatever we think of new physics-related questions, the tag is needed to properly classify the existing questions. Even off-topic questions should be tagged correctly, until or unless they are deleted.
2. Not all physics-related questions are off-topic here. The border between physics and mathematics is fuzzy. A question about fluid dynamics, or general relativity, etc, can be a perfectly valid mathematical question.

#### Aside

Apparently, you raised  this question because you came across [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1284832/147263). You commented:

> Abdullah there's a stack exchange site for physics so ask it there!

This was *not* a good suggestion: such a post would be immediately closed on the Physics site. In general, you should not recommend sites that you are not familiar with. If you think the question is off-topic here, then suggest it to be closed as off-topic (vote to close if you have 3000 rep; flag "should be closed" otherwise).

Comment: "Half knowledge is dangerous" so I just raised question as I thought so .I never knew it would be closed in the physics site. That's all. My bad giving a suggestion without knowing properly. Thanks for answering as this gave me a good lesson as well.